# Загрузка файла ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api

Есть гугл карта апи, где каждый может оставть марку, где будет отображатся информация о пропавших животных, пытаюсь сделать возможным загружать фотографии, но пока безуспешно.

Собитие при клики по карте:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {

                var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
                '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajax-save.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
                '<label for="pUpload"><input type="file" accept="image/*" name="pUpload" class="save-upload"></label>'+
                '</form>'+
                '</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">'+saveMark+'</button>';

                create_marker(event.latLng, info, EditForm, true, true, true, "#");
            });
```

В функции create_marker():

```
var mUpload = $('input.save-upload')[0].files;
save_marker(mUpload)
```

В функции save_marker()

```
var myData = new FormData();
          myData.append ( 'file', mUpload);
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "map_process.php",
          processData: false, 
          contentType: false, 
          data: myData,
          success:function(data){

          var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

В map_process.php

```
$etc = var_dump($_FILES);
die($etc);
```

И var_dump показывает что пусто, не могу понять, где я что то пропустил, полный javascript: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tntfo9L/)

Answer (score 1):

У вас form action="ajax-save.php", возможно, в нём проблема.

Comment: Не в нем, кроме файла, отправляются другие данные, с ними все ок.

Comment: Поставил перед var myData = new FormData(); console.log(mUpload); показывает [object FileList], значит файл доходит до формы, верно?

Comment: Когда я делаю подобное,обычно ставлю аргумент для FormData, например, 
`var myForm = $('input.SaveMarker')[0];
var myData = new FormData(myForm );`

Comment: Если console.log сработал, то до myData он дошёл. Как я понимаю, у Вас нет ошибки в запросе, но данные не передаются. Нужно искать причину в неправильном назначении данных.