# Ajax + PHP. Загрузка файла

Tags: php, ajax, upload

прошу помощи. Использую такой вот код

```
function formSubmit(form, input) {
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(form).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(form).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(form).attr('action'), // the file to call
        beforeSend: function(response) {
            $('#' + $(form).attr('name') + $(form).attr('id') + 'Result').html('<img id="loading-image" width=40px src="img/ajax-loader.svg" />'); // Loader https://loading.io/
            $("#loading-image").show();
           },
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#' + $(form).attr('name') + $(form).attr('id') + 'Result').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    }); 
}
```

```
<form name="form" id="1" action="ajax.php" method="POST">

    <input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="uploadFile" />
    <input class="button" name="add" value="Добавить" type="button" onclick="formSubmit(this.form)">

</form>
<div id="form1Result"></div>
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как его модифицировать, чтобы можно было загружать файл на сервер?

**Главная задача - не сломать работу этого скрипта, так как он используется во многих местах.**

Спасибо!

Comment: Не поверишь - в интернете __ахулиард__ туториалов, как загрузить файл с помощью ajax. И все они находятся запросом "загрузка файла ajax". Вот даже тут есть вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544012/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-ajax?rq=1 Пожалуйста.

Comment: Поверю и уже это сделал, но задача именно допилить этот скрипт, не сломав его работу, так как он используется во многих местах. А а JS у меня слабо, поэтому спрашиваю совета.